# how to test classifier model in weka?

Tags: weka, data-mining

I have a dataset of about 7000 records. After clearing, I performed normalization and discretization operations on it.Then I applied a j48 model to it and saved it to my computer.Now I want to test this model on a dataset of 500 records. All columns in this dataset are the same as the original dataset. However, the "class" column in the test dataset has no value. But I got an error. For this reason, I also applied normalization and discretization operations to the test dataset. But I still get this error. Note that I specified the class attribute in both datasets, but again this error was displayed.

this is a screenshot of my test file:
[test arff file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbQWL.png)

and this is a screenshot of my train dataset file:
[train arff file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsu1S.png)

can anybody help me?

Comment: Your image does not show what you have for the class value in the test set.  You say `However, the "class" column in the test dataset has no value.` When you say "no value, do you mean that it is blank?  That is not the right way to leave it unspecified for WEKA.  Instead, put a ? (question mark) in for the class value.

Comment: Yes I was going to make a class prediction using the stored model. But by mistake I had taken the test path of my algorithm. I'm looking for a way to predict a valueless class right now. If you have any training in this area please let me know.
thank you

Comment: Your images do not show the class variable. Can you show what you have for the class variable in the test data?